# Google Calendar integrating

Tags: reactjs, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have an issue when integrating with Google Calendar using react-google-calendar-api library

but Im facing an error ReferenceError: gapi is not defined

```
import ApiCalendar from 'react-google-calendar-api';
const config = {
  clientId: clientId,
  apiKey: apiKet,
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
  discoveryDocs: [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest',],
};
const apiCalendar = new ApiCalendar(config);
const GoogleCalender = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    apiCalendar.handleAuthClick();
    apiCalendar.listEvents({
      timeMin: new Date().toISOString(),
      timeMax: new Date().toISOString(),
      showDeleted: true,
      maxResults: 10,
      orderBy: 'updated',
    }).then((result) => {
      console.log(result, 'ggggggggggggggg');
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Have you already imported the Calendar API Library using npm as referenced here in this [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-calendar-api)?